# Multi file upload with PHP/Javascript and no flash

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

I'm trying to make a webpage that allows the uploading of multiple files at the same times. I will limit the file extensions to the most common images like JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF.

I've done some research on this and everywhere I look it's flash this and flash that.

I don't want to use flash really. Especially with Flash 10, which disables the most common used method to enable multifile upload.

What I'm looking for is a way to keep creating more and more input fields, each with a browse button and then with one final upload button at the bottom of the form. Creating the new input fields with a Javascript is nog big deal really.

So I'm wondering how this works. Do I need to give all file-input fields the same name atribute so I can use 1 piece of PHP code to solve this? Or Is there some way for PHP to detect howmany files have been sumbitted and simply put the code for parsing a file inside a for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the algorithm:

You add the new file input fields to your form. Each of this field MUST have a unique name. Then, on the server side, you loop through the $_FILES array looking how many files have been uploaded and handling them.

Comment: to make the fields all have a unique name, it would be as simple to create a var i = 0; in Javascript. Then via Javascript, replace the name of each field with "name + i++"

Comment: yes, but you don't need to because PHP will deal with it for you if you suffix the name with []

Answer (score 12):

You can keep adding 'file' inputs but use a name of something like 'upload[]'

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]">
```

Then in $_FILES['upload'] you will have an array of files you can loop over like

```
foreach ($_FILES['upload'] as $file) {
    echo $file['size'];
}
```

Comment: So basically, php will view the name attribute as an array. This way, I can also keep track of exact upload time :)

And i take it the $file['size'] 'size' part is meant to be the number which I have to implement?

Comment: $file['size'] is equivalent to $_FILES['controlname']['size'], it was just an example. so $file will contain everything you need to handle the upload

Answer (score 0):

In using JavaScript to add new upload fields, you could also have JavaScript update some "hidden" input field with the number of upload fields in the form.  That way, once you click Submit, that hidden value should be submitted and it will be trivial to parse out the $_FILES array for all the uploaded files.

Comment: not really necessary, what would be wrong with doing count($_FILES) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reasonable maximum limit on the number of files, it's probably better to include that many file upload fields in the static form, then use the JavaScript to hide the superfluous ones, than to create them all dynamically. Then the form can still work when JavaScript is unavailable.

Side note: technically, single HTML file upload forms are already multiple file upload forms. According to the HTML form encoding standard, one should be able to select multiple files in the Browse dialogue box, and they'd be submitted as a multipart/mixed MIME structure.

However, almost nothing actually supports this. Older versions of Opera do on the client-side (and, I think, an ancient test browser of some sort, possibly Viola), and a few form-parsing components on the server-side, but not the PHP built-ins. In any case the UI is not very usable, so you're not missing much.

Comment: there is no real limit, but I've added a Javascript that enables more input fields. I can simply limit that amount.

Also, in php I can simply do a check wheter or not a certain field is filled and skip to the next if nothing is entered.