# non flash multi file upload for php

Tags: java, php, upload, gears

looking into multi file - drag and drop - upload scripts.
we were using swfupload until flash 10 destroyed it.
the other options we are investigating are java and google gears.
what would you recommend and do you know of libraries/examples/frameworks that support these options like the swfupload.
thanks,
Josh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi file upload with PHP/Javascript and no flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276400/multi-file-upload-with-php-javascript-and-no-flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem. The latest version of SWFUpload does work, and it does so by transparently overlaying the swf on top of your 'select files' button.

This will work. The reason Flash 10 broke the old one, is because (for security reasons) it forces the end-user to initiate the process through a click, instead of allowing scripts to invoke this.

Instead of using all the swfupload javascript, we did actually end up rewriting that entire library (and cutting down the javascript code to about a 10th of the original).

Comment: thanks - i did see this but wasn't sure how effective or stable this solution was - a bit of a hack maybe. can you post your updated code somewhere - i'd be interested to see it.

Comment: It is definitely a bit of a hack.. I can't at the moment post the code.. It wouldn't be much good anyway, because it's closely integrated in our app..

However the things I've done are the following:
  * I've added a new flashvar, which allows me to specify exactly which javascript callback to call (instead of the hardcoded swfupload js objects)
  * I've simply rewrite the javascript with all the methods, and implemented exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
    
Reference: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/2.html

Comment: aha, sorry about that. could you be more explicit on what features you want from this file uploader?

Comment: we were happy with the swfupload script. the multiple files is the key with drag and drop as a bonus - anything that isn't selecting each file individually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/index.html) previously in some PHP projects of mine.  Great for uploading multiple files on the fly, including chunk-splitting them to get past any `upload_max_file` restrictions.  Also, its pretty customizable to make it work exactly how you want it to.